# Sphere Volume Calculator

Tags: javascript, calculator, volume

Hello I am making a volume calculator and I can't seem to get the volume to display on screen. Would doing an alert solve this? This assignment requires me to use anonymous functions so I am having a hard time getting the function to run.

```
HTML
 <body>
 <h3> Calculate the Volume of a Sphere <h3>
 <label for="radius">Radius </label>
 <input id="radius" name="radius"  required>
 </input>

 <button id="calc" onclick=sphereVol> calculate </button>

JavaScript

 var sphereVol = function(radius){
 var c = (4/3) * Math.PI * Math.pow(radius, 3);
 return c;
 }
```

Comment: you need to read the radius value from the input in your function and then either alert the volume or print it on the screen. Try finding ways of doing it. There are plenty resources available for doing this. Still if you are stuck the you can always come back here with whatever you tried and get some help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get the radius from the input and the output it somewhere. You could use `alert()` or `console.log()` but it's nicer if you can output to the page. [`document.getElementById()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) is a fundamental way of getting elements from the DOM and [`value`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/text#Value) can help get the input. Here's a super-simplified version:

```js
var sphereVol = function() {
  // get the radius
  let radius = document.getElementById('radius').value
  var c = (4 / 3) * Math.PI * Math.pow(radius, 3);
  // display the result
  document.getElementById('result').textContent = "Volume ≈ " + c.toFixed(4);
}
```

```html
<h3> Calculate the Volume of a Sphere
</h3>
<label for="radius">Radius </label>
<input id="radius" name="radius" required>
</input>

<button id="calc" onclick="sphereVol()"> calculate </button>
<div id="result">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to manipulate the DOM to receive the input and to show the output. Your function is right, but here's one way of manipulating the DOM:

HTML

```
<body>
 <h3> Calculate the Volume of a Sphere <h3>
 <label for="radius">Radius </label>
 <input id="radius" name="radius" required>

 <button id="calc" onclick=sphereVol()> calculate </button>

 <p>Your volume:</p>
 <p id="outputVolume"></p>
```

JavaScript

```
 var sphereVol = function(){
    var radius = document.getElementById("radius").value;
    var c = (4/3) * Math.PI * Math.pow(radius, 3);

    document.getElementById("outputVolume").innerHTML = c;
 }
```

What changed:

- I *called* the function in the onclick `sphereVol` by saying `sphereVol()`
- I looked up the volume
- I changed the HTML to show the result

**Further Reading:**

1. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById
2. https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_text_value.asp
3. https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_html.asp

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of bugs in your program. I have improved your code and also read the comment in each line.

```js
<html>
 <body>
 <h3> Calculate the Volume of a Sphere <h3>
 <label for="radius">Radius </label>
 <input id="radius" name="radius"  required>
 </input>
 <!-- I added double quote around sphereVol variable which holds the annonymous function  and also have to provide parenthesis for it. -->
 <button id="calc" onclick="sphereVol()"> calculate </button>
 <p id="result"></p>
<script>

 var sphereVol = function(){
 //Reading input radius here
 radius = document.getElementById("radius").value;
 var c = (4/3) * Math.PI * Math.pow(radius, 3);
 console.log(c);
 document.getElementById("result").innerHTML="The volume is: "+c;
 }
 </script>
 </body>
</html>
```